# Docker configuration on Synology - https://github.com/jlesage/docker-crashplan-pro upgrade issue

Tags: docker, synology

I'm running the docker crashplan image (https://github.com/jlesage/docker-crashplan-pro) on my Synology NAS. I'm a bit confused on how to update without loosing the existing configuration.

According to the description the following steps should be taken when upgrading:
https://github.com/jlesage/docker-crashplan-pro#synology

Step 9 states:

> Clear the container by clicking Action->Clear. This removes the container while keeping its configuration.

When I follow the instructions, all the settings and configurations are gone when I reboot the docker image. I have to setup the image as if it was a new setup every time. It feels like I have not setup the configuration to be "outside" the image itself, what is listed as a parameter in the description:

> -v /docker/appdata/crashplan-pro:/config:rw \

but I am unsure how to setup this path using Synology's docker.

Does anyone have an idea what I have forgotten?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Action > Clear wipes the configuration, so after re-starting Crashplan container, it thinks this is a new PC & asks:   Add New Device or Replace Existing

But, instead choosing 'Add New Device' & starting the backup process from scratch, choose 'Replace Existing' because you can skip the part where it want to restore all the files from your backup onto your PC, so...
choose 'Replace Existing' (as stated above)
for 'Device to Replace', choose your PC's name
choose 'Skip File Transfer' to not restore any data from the existing backup
and lastly click Continue on 'Transfer Settings to New Device'

If will synchronize file information, fairly quickly & you'll be back to where you started.

Comment: Yeah, that's one option, but it feels a lot more cumbersome than an ordinary upgrade on a (non-Docker) client. Is there no way to keep the configuration across upgrades?